# LSTM network for space-invaders RL (Keras)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, reinforcement-learning

i´m new to reinforcement learning, and was trying to use LSTM for reinforcement learning for a space invaders agent. 
I tried to use the network found in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06527.pdf) but I kept having trouble:

-If i use conv2D the dimensions with the LSTM dont fit and i get this error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv_lst_m2d_1:
>   expected ndim=5, found ndim=4

This is the code:

```
    self.model = Sequential()
    self.model.add(Conv2D(32,kernel_size=8,strides=4,activation='relu',input_shape=(None,84,84,1)))
    self.model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=4,strides=2,activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3, strides=1,activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(ConvLSTM2D(512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', return_sequences=False))
    self.model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
    self.model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001))
    self.model.summary()
```

-And if I use Conv3D that outputs a 5D tensor I cant use one image as an input:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv3d_1_input to have
>   5 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 84, 84, 1)

Code:

```
    self.model.add(Conv3D(32,kernel_size=8,strides=4,activation='relu',input_shape=(None,84,84,1)))
    self.model.add(Conv3D(64,kernel_size=4,strides=2,activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(Conv3D(64,kernel_size=3, strides=1,activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(ConvLSTM2D(512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', return_sequences=False))
    self.model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
    self.model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001))
    self.model.summary()
```

(edit)

Network summary(of the second network):

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv3d_1 (Conv3D)            (None, None, 20, 20, 32)  16416     
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_2 (Conv3D)            (None, None, 9, 9, 64)    131136    
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_3 (Conv3D)            (None, None, 7, 7, 64)    110656    
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_1 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, 7, 7, 512)         10618880  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 7, 7, 4)           2052      
=================================================================
```

And data input shape is: `(84, 84, 1)`

Comment: The first error you get refers to the `ConvLSTM2D` layer, therefore your initial choice of layers seems to work. Can you print the network summary and include in the question as well as an input sample/shape?

Comment: The first network doesn't print a summary, because the network isn't even constructing... Just realizing the other one does construct the network and outputs the error when we input the images.

Comment: The second network is compiling but the input shape of the Conv_3D layer is not working for the shape of your data. On the other hand, the first network is not compiling as the output size of the last Conv_2d layer is not working with the input size of the ConvLSTM layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [TimeDistributed](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TimeDistributed) Conv2D, it tells your network to understand the data as temporal (which I guess is what you want) and will match the LSTM inner shape.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,84,84,1)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,kernel_size=8,strides=4,activation='relu')))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=4,strides=2,activation='relu')))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3, strides=1,activation='relu')))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', return_sequences=False))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001))

model.summary()
```

Compile returns :

```
Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
time_distributed_12 (TimeDis (None, None, 20, 20, 32)  2080      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_13 (TimeDis (None, None, 9, 9, 64)    32832     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_14 (TimeDis (None, None, 7, 7, 64)    36928     
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_3 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, 7, 7, 512)         10618880  
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_15 (TimeDis (None, 7, 7, 4)           2052      
=================================================================
Total params: 10,692,772
Trainable params: 10,692,772
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to print input and output details of your model:-

o/p will be like this -

Input to marks model:

```
[{'name': 'input', 'index': 451, 'shape': array([  1, 160, 160,   3],
dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0,
0)}]
```

Output of marks model:

```
[{'name': 'embeddings', 'index': 450, 'shape': array([  1, 512], dtype=int32), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>, 'quantization': (0.0, 0)}]
```

once you will get details, according to the details you will have to give the value of `input_shape`.